# this.sequelize.isDefined Node Modules?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to seed into a database. I have successfully seeded using 2 other models, but when I try to seed data into a Model called 'Comment', I get this error:
TypeError: this.sequelize.isDefined is not a function

It has only happened for this particular model, even though the syntax is practically identical to the other two. Has anyone gotten this error before?

Here is the seed.js file. I commented out the Comment section (the one that doesn't work) but the other two are just fine.

```
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');
const { User, Post, Comment } = require('../models');

const userData = require('./usersSeed.json');
const postData = require('./postsSeed.json');
const commentData = require('./commentSeed.json')

const seedDatabase = async () => {
  await sequelize.sync({ force: true });

  await User.bulkCreate(userData, {
    individualHooks: true,
    returning: true,
  });

  await Post.bulkCreate(postData, {
    individualHooks: true,
    returning: true,
  });

/*    await Comment.bulkCreate(commentData,
     {
      individualHooks: true,
      returning: true,
    }); */

  process.exit(0);
};

seedDatabase();
```

Here is a model that works fine

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');


class Post extends Model {}

Post.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        post_title: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        },
        post_text: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true,
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: 'user',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        date_posted: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        }
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true,
        modelName: 'post',
    }
)

module.exports = Post;
```

Here is the Comment model

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

class Comment extends Model {}

Comment.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        comment_text: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        },
        post_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'post',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'user',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: false,
        modelName: 'comment'
    }
)

module.exports = Comment;
```

Here is the index for the Models

```
const User = require('./User');
const Post = require('./Post');
const Comment = require('./Comment')

User.hasMany(Post, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id'
});

Post.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id',
});
Comment.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id'
  });
  
Comment.belongsTo(Post, {
    foreignKey: 'post_id'
});
  
User.hasMany(Comment, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id'
});
  
Post.hasMany(Comment, {
    foreignKey: 'post_id'
});

module.exports = { User, Post, Comment};
```

Comment: We need to look at both seeds: one with no errors and another one with the error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wow so dumb. I needed to change the sequelize variable to require the connection

```
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');
```